# Test empty token in FOR /F Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, is-empty

I'm trying to split a string with the format: client_subfolder_filename
into three variable :
`client`, `subfolder` and `filename` (which would include the extension too)

But I can't manage to test if the parsing failed (in which case the file is not a valid file and should be ignored)

I have tried `==""`, `==[]`, `not defined`, `not exist`, but nothing seems to work. Ideally, I would like to test if `client`, `subfolder` or `fileName` is an empty string

Here is my script

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
::mainDir is the directory where the customerfolders and the scripts are located
set mainDir=C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyScript\src
cd %mainDir%
cd FilesToMove
set /a count=1

set client=""
set subfolder=""
set fileName=""


for %%i in (*) do (
  echo       !count! %%i
  set /a count=count+1

  for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=_" %%a in ("%%i") do (
    set client=%%a
    set subfolder=%%b
    set fileName=%%c

    if "!subfolder!" == "" goto NEXT
    if "!fileName!" == "" goto NEXT
    if not exist "%mainDir%\!client!\!subfolder!\" (mkdir "%mainDir%\!client!\!subfolder!")
    move %%i "%mainDir%"\!client!\!subfolder!\!fileName!"
    :NEXT
  )
)
```

Comment: You can't use a `GOTO` inside a `FOR` command.  It breaks out of the FOR command. That is your main problem.  Regardless of that, why bother using delayed expansion.  Just use the `FOR` variables directly with all your other commands. Also, DO NOT do this: `set client=""`. You are assigning quotes to the variable.  If you want to make it undefined then do this: `set "client="`

Comment: You also have an extra quote in this command: `move %%i "%mainDir%"\!client!\!subfolder!\!fileName!"`.  Remove the one in the middle.

Comment: Thanks @Squashman for your indications. I have managed to clean the code and make it way more intuitive. Sadly, I am still unable to find the proper condition to test if `%%b` or `%%c` are null (as `if not define %%b` is always true even when `%%b` has a value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a GOTO inside a FOR command. It breaks out of the FOR command. That is your main problem. Regardless of that, why bother using delayed expansion. Just use the FOR variables directly with all your other commands. Also, DO NOT do this: `set client=""`. You are assigning quotes to the variable. If you want to make it undefined then do this: `set "client="`.

To test for `%%b` and `%%c` being empty use both of them at the same time in an `IF` command. Reverse the sequence on one side.  When they are not equal, then you know both of them are populated.

Here is how I would code your script.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM mainDir is the directory where the customerfolders and the scripts are located
set mainDir=C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyScript\src
cd %mainDir%
cd FilesToMove
set /a count=0

for %%i in (*) do (
    set /a count+=1
    echo       !count! %%i
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=_" %%a in ("%%i") do (
        rem client=%%a
        rem subfolder=%%b
        rem fileName=%%c
        if NOT "%%b%%c"=="%%c%%b" (
            mkdir "%mainDir%\%%a\%%c"  >nul 2>&1
            move "%%~i" "%mainDir%\%%a\%%b\%%c"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly! May I know what the difference is between "%%~i" and "%%i", both seem to work in my tests so I guess your way covers some cases I haven't thought of

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type: `for /?` This will bring up the help file for the `FOR` command. Read the very last section.